# Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled(true) depreciated in Swift

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

In iOS/xCode/Swift, since I upgraded to the latest version of the Flurry iOS SDK I get "`Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled is depreciated`".

This is my code:

```
...
//start flurry
Flurry.setCrashReportingEnabled(true)
Flurry.startSession(environment.flurryAPIKey)
...
```

looking at the [Flurry iOS SDK GitHub project](https://github.com/flurry/flurry-ios-sdk/blob/master/Flurry/Flurry.h) I found "deprecated since 7.7.0, please use FlurrySessionBuilder in place of calling this API."

However I cannot find any info regarding this FlurrySessionBuilder usage in Swift.
How to convert the above code to using this FlurrySessionBuilder to get rid of this depreciated warning?

Answer (score 1):

After contact support Flurry support I finally found the answer here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios/#initialize-flurry

```
let builder = FlurrySessionBuilder.init()
                                  .withAppVersion("1.0")
                                  .withLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll)
                                  .withCrashReporting(true)
                                  .withSessionContinueSeconds(10)

// Replace YOUR_API_KEY with the api key in the downloaded package
Flurry.startSession("YOUR_API_KEY", with: builder)
```